# Physical meaning of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well i've been trying to understand this differential equation
\begin{equation} \label{eq:2.1}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{dx}{dt}=r_1x(1-\dfrac{x+\beta_1y}{K})\\\\
&\dfrac{dy}{dt} = y(-r_2+\alpha_1 x-d_2y)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where:

$x$ - crow population density

$y$ - cuckoos' population density

$r_1$ - intrinsic growth rate of crows

$K$ - carrying capacity when in isolation

$r_2$ - death rate of cuckoos

$d_2$ - self-incompatible degree

$\beta_1$ - quantity of resources consumed by a cuckoo

$\alpha_1$ - efficiency of cuckoos in converting the consumption into fitness

The differential came from the parasitism of a cuckoo to that of a crow. What I want to know is what is the meaning of the term $$(1-\dfrac{x+\beta_1y}{K})$$ in the first equation? It's some sort of a logistic equation, but I can't seem to grasp it's meaning since the equation was based on a Holling Type I functional response.

Comment: I can't make sense of $\beta_1y$ given that it has units of population density. Also, what does K mean beyond the definition you gave?

Comment: It only says to the journal that the equations are based, that the term $-\beta_1 y$ denotes the parasitism of cuckoos. And regarding $K$ as I have defined, was only defined as the carrying capacity when in isolation for the crow.

Comment: You can think of it as a stress factor that reduces the growth of the crow population. The more there are of crows and cuckoos, relative to the carrying capacity, the higher the stress and the less reproductive activity.

Comment: @LutzL thank you very much :)